# Triggers en MySql

Tags: mysql, trigger

necesito ayuda por favor...Tengo el siguiente código para realizar auditoria en una tabla (si se inserta, actualiza o elimina un dato), pero me sale el error SQL(1064), quisiera saber cual es la forma correcta de realizar un trigger en MYSQL teniendo varias condicionales.

```
CREATE TRIGGER I_auditar_empresas
AFTER INSERT or UPDATE or DELETE ON empresa 
FOR EACH ROW
    if inserting then 
        INSERT INTO auditoria (nom_tabla,accion,fecha) VALUES ('EMPRESA','INSERTAR', NOW())
    END if;

    if updating then 
        INSERT INTO auditoria (nom_tabla,accion,fecha) VALUES ('EMPRESA','ACTUALIZAR', NOW())
    end if;

    if deleting then 
        INSERT INTO auditoria(nom_tabla,accion,fecha) VALUES ('EMPRESA','ELIMINAR', NOW())
    end if;
end I_auditar_empresas;
```

Comment: Hacen falta 2 cosas importantes: el mensaje de error completo y que describas mejor lo que pretendes lograr con este trigger

Comment: Sólo puedes agregar un trigger por operación, y por momento, es decir uno para antes o después de insertar o actualizar o borrar, no puedes utilizar todas al mismo tiempo ya que hay objetos dentro de la función que dependerán de ello. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html

Answer (score 2):

Sólo se puede especificar uno de {BEFORE | AFTER}, a eso se refiere la documentación. También sólo puedes especificar si es para la operación INSERT o UPDATE o DELETE, no las tres.

Lo que puedes hacer para encapsular la lógica es crear un procedimiento almacenado, que reciba los tres parámetros y sólo tendrías que implementarlo para después de cada operación (AFTER) llamando dentro del trigger al SP porque el BEFORE no tendría mucho sentido, sólo te interesa si se hizo alguna operación (Insert, Update o Delete).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html